# Photoluminescence Spectroscopy- Two individual spots, different colors, but same emission spectra

Tags: visible-light, semiconductor-physics

my apologies in advance if I'm not posting at the right site, but StackExchange-Physics is the closest one that relates to this question.

Method: Photoluminescence spectroscopy

Sample being studied: a mm-size crystal with rough surface, and unequal height

What's confusing me: On the same crystal, a spot that emits purple light and another spot that emits blue light have the same PL spectra. Why?

Here're my guesses and I was hoping someone could suggest other/a more concrete causes with reference.

Guess 1. [Premise: the purple spot has a much brighter PL intensity than the blue spot] The blue and the purple spots have different emission spectra, and the blue area has some faint purple emission that's unnoticeable by eye, but since the purple emission lot more intense than the blue emission, the spectrum for the blue spot is shadowed by that of the purple spot, so for each spot I see the same spectrum.

Guess 2. Blue and the purple spots are exactly the same so they should have the same spectrum, but since the crystal has an uneven surface some of the blue/purple light gets scattered, resulting in a different color than what's originally emitting.

Thanks!

Comment: is "purple" and "blue" what you see by eye? You are aware of color perception in this case? http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/colper.html

Answer (score 1):

A few questions that might be useful for us

- How are you measuring the PL, many spectroscopy tools have difficulty resolving small areas, so what does your set-up or tool look like?
- How do you observe the spots?
- What do you use to induce the PL?
- Do you wear glasses (possibly with anti-glare filter)?
- For guess 2, is the surface roughness at some point maybe periodic, have you observed it under high magnification, possibly an electron microscope?
- Very importantly does the PL tool/set-up use any optical filter and what is the orientation of the crystal with regards to the spots?
- Also can you see the 2 spots under most angles or only if you hold the crystal under a specific angle?

I have an idea of what be happening maybe but I need most of those first.
If optical filters are involved I can exactly tell you what's going on, there are some other options but there are less likely.

**Edit,** if you don't have all the answers immediately start by answering some of the questions. Someone might already be able to tell you what's going on or at least take an educated guess.

**Edit 2,** reply to comments:
Something that I mentioned and that is quite critical is the distance between the spots. Doesn't have to be exact but if it's less than 2 or 3 mm, chances are high that you exciting both at the same time. Explain precisely what's going on and update it in your main post please.
Lasers usually end up creating spotsizes of about 0.5 to 1mm in diameter, however dimension down to 0.1mm or up to 5 mm are not all that uncommon. 
[Calculate the spotsize and take it into account](http://www.ophiropt.com/laser--measurement/laser-power-energy-meters/services/focal-spot-size-calculator-for-gaussian-beams)

SAED is not necessary, normal or high-res (immersion) SEM is completely fine and easily allows for samples of several mm, and often even up to a few cm. I don't want you to go down to the crystal lattice (several nm) but I want to see if there are periodic structures in the hundreds of nm range or a few um. Look up how a butterfly wing works:
[image: SEM images of blue butterfly wing]

Now optical filters (interference ones especially) do not act the same when light hits it from different angles. If light comes in from a different angle than incidence it does not block/pass the exact same light. Many normal glasses have anti-glare polarizers and coatings which can affect color(-perception) when viewing things under an angle. Laser goggles might block more than they say if light hits it under a specific angle (not a 100% sure about this, probably depends on the laser goggles used). Interference filters that are supposed to block the laser-light (and possibly other background light) can block additional/different wavelengths if the spot isn't straight under (perpendicular) the objective and the lenses. [image: Shift in notch filter for AOI]

Now the first thing you can do to check if it's due to your eyes/goggles, is when you see the spot move around the sample and see if the spot is visible from different angles at the same location. If it is, good then you've most likely confirmed that it's actually there. Then decrease the power of the laser and see if it disappears at the same time as the purple spot. If it disappears earlier, then we know it's weaker most likely and it probably indicates that it's a secondary induced PL. Which can sometimes actually be excited by it's own PL at a lower wavelength.
[As you can see in these paper some crystal can also have multiple PL wavelengths at the same time.](https://www.osapublishing.org/DirectPDFAccess/9356543F-02C3-C03E-FA87274EEFE1476F_350971/ome-6-11-3446.pdf?da=1&id=350971&seq=0&mobile=no) 
If by this time we still don't know what's causing it, put it under a SEM and check if the surface is periodic or not.

Comment: The PL setup looks like this (https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Schematic-diagram-of-the-photoluminescence-setup_fig8_30010687)
I observe the spots through a microscope objective which is directly above the sample.
To induce PL, I used a 375nm laser. 
My goggles block 190nm-398nm radiation.
The surface roughness doesn't seem periodic, though certain areas are flatter than other. SAED is not possible because the sample thickness is too large.
I don't know if the set-up uses an optical filter (why do you ask?), and how do I find out crystal orientation?
Have not tried.Why? 
Thanks!

Comment: @Zhen I've updated my post, with **edit 2** to answer some of the question and ask some more things as there's isn't that much space in a comment.

Comment: @Zhen please keep me updated and let us know if you are able to figure more things or if you think you know what's causing it.

Comment: @Zhen are there any updates?

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for following up. I haven't gotten around to work on this yet, but I plan on doing so this week. Will keep you posted!

Comment: Also could you resend the link for (or tell me the names of) the article about the crystal having multiple wavelengths? The link you sent earlier didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: https://www.osapublishing.org/DirectPDFAccess/9356543F-02C3-C03E-FA87274EEFE1476F_350971/ome-6-11-3446.pdf?da=1&id=350971&seq=0&mobile=no

Comment: @Zhen good to know, the paper is called Large photoluminescence enhancement of
Er3+ : GdVO4 crystal in both green and middle
infrared regions under moderate low magnetic
fields, published in 2016 at optical materials express by JUNPEI ZHANG, et al.

Comment: @Zhen any updates?